# IE div width + scrollbar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a modal UI in my web app that necessitates a fixed layout design. After much fussing, I decided absolutely positioned child elements was the way to go. However, I have one div that conditionally requires a vertical scrollbar (if there's too much content). When this scrollbar is added, the width of the div seems to vary between IE 7 and IE 8.

IE8 standards mode:

[image]

IE7 standards mode:

[image]

I haven't even tested for IE 6, but I'm sure it's even funkier. What's the simplest, least painful way to address this to arrive at a consistent UI in all major browsers?

Comment: Any chance you could make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case to mess around with?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just float the thumbnails left instead of absolute positioning? It would be much more consistent over browsers. Than wrap it all in a div with a fixed height and set it's overflow to auto.

Comment: Ideally, I want the scroll bar to be right aligned with the edge of the modal window. If I do it the way you suggest, there's no guarantee that it will be, as the width is variable depending on how the browser calculates the width (before or after adding the scrollbar).

Comment: No the width is always 100% of a div since it's a block element so the scrollbar will be always to the right. Unless you have less elements and no scroll is needed.